# About Optional orElse and orElseGet

Tags: java, generics, option-type

```
HashMap<String,Object> other = new HashMap<>();
new ArrayList<String>().stream().map(s -> new HashMap<String, Object>() {{
  }}).findFirst().orElse(other);
Stream.generate(() -> new HashMap<String, Object>()).findFirst().orElse(other);
```

The second statement of the code has a compilation error

[image]

Please tell me where there is a problem

Comment: Please don't link to pictures of code, include the code itself in your post.

Comment: You probably don't have your JDK set properly, or you have defined your own `String` and `Object` classes

Comment: I did not use other String and Object, JDK is also set correctly

Comment: Read the answers to [What is Double Brace initialization in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1958636/2711488), especially the reasons why you shouldn’t use it. One of the reasons will guide you to your current problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the second statement, `new HashMap<String, Object>() {{ }}` statement creates an anonymous inner class. The result is not a direct instance of `HashMap<String, Object>` anymore, but a class derived from it.

You should remove the curly brackets:

```
HashMap<String,Object> other = new HashMap<>();
new ArrayList<String>().stream().map(s -> new HashMap<String, Object>()).findFirst().orElse(other);
```